# Subclassing SCNScene and SceneKit Editor

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have SCNScene subclass with a camera setup, that I want to use in all the subclasses.

```
let scene01 = TheSubclassScene()
let scene02 = TheSubclassScene(named:"art.scnassets/testScene.scn")!
self.sceneArray.addObject(scene01)
self.sceneArray.addObject(scene02)
```

I want to change the scenes at runtime. This works when I create the scene in code but not with a scene from the SceneKit Editor. So `scene01` is working but `scene02` isn't. In the debugger I can see the two scenes in the array. One is of type SCNSceneSubclass but the other is of type SCNScene.

Is there any way to get this working?

Update:
This is my scene subclass

```
class TheSubclassScene: SCNScene
{
    let cameraNode = CameraNode()

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        self.rootNode.addChildNode(self.cameraNode)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a workaround for that problem. Not nice but it works. I instantiate a `SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/testScene.scn")` then I instantiate a `TheSubclassScene()` and I clone the rootNode of the scene and add it as a child node to the subclass scene.

```
let testScene = SCNScene(named:"art.scnassets/testScene.scn")!
let subclassScene = TheSubclassScene()
subclassScene.rootNode.addChildNode(testScene.rootNode.clone())
```

Answer (score 1):

`.scn` files are just `SCNScene` instances archived and written to disk using `NSKeyedArchiver`. What `+ sceneNamed:` does is that it simply unarchives the scene with a `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

What you could do then, is to try to use `- setClass:forClassName:` to instantiate a subclass instead of a `SCNScene`.

That being said, `SCNScene` is not really meant to be subclassed. Instead you could implement your logic in the view controller or a game controller (possibly a direct subclass of `NSObject`). This controller will also likely conform to `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` to implement your game logic.

Answer (score 0):

Note: don't give your custom subclass a name starting with "SCN"; that prefix is for Apple.

The only difference I can see is calling `SCNSceneSubclass(named:)` vs `SCNSceneSubclass()`. Without seeing your code, my hunch is that your implementation of `SCNSceneSubclass(named:)` does not call through to your subclass's initialization, and thus misses some key steps.

Can we see a bit of your subclass's source code?

Comment: SCNSceneSubclass is just in example. In my code it has a name without SCN prefix. The subclass is just adding a camera node at initialisation.

Comment: I provided the subclass code. Nothing wrong there in my opinion. Is there any way to override the convenience init(named name: String) ? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: You don't have to call it that. But I don't think that's the problem. What do we know about testScene.scn? Does it have any nodes that you can see in the debugger? Can you load it into a straight SCNScene (not your subclass)? Can you see it using Quicklook or Preview? What happens if you load a different file into your subclass?

Comment: testScene is fine as well, just a box inside the scene and I can load it in an SCNScene. Quicklook works as well. Different file, same problem.